# Bash in Ubuntu WSL requires restart to initialize pyenv

Tags: bash, python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, virtualenv

I have a small but very strange issue with pyenv in Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL. When I start a shell then try to activate a virtual environment, I get the same issue as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45577194/failed-to-activate-virtualenv-with-pyenv?newreg=6d05e39c69f747f1aa0665f00ed129b7

However I have ~/.bashrc set up as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), and if I restart the shell using `exec $SHELL` then virtualenv works properly. This made me think ~/.bashrc was not executing when opening a new window for some reason, but I checked and it clearly is. I installed pyenv and pyenv-virtualenv with Homebrew.

Why would a newly opened shell not load virtualenv, but then load after a restart?

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

# add files to path
alias atom="/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /c 'atom'"

if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
  eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
fi
```

Comment: Can you include your `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` scripts here as code blocks?

Comment: Added my ~/.bashrc script. There isn't a ~/.bash_profile script in my home folder. Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to invoke a shell.  When you log into a system, either with a terminal emulator (such as when you start WSL) or via SSH, such a shell is called a login shell.  Any shell you start and type commands into, whether or not it is also a login shell, is called an interactive shell.  A non-interactive shell is any shell that is used for scripting or otherwise in a way where you don't type commands into it.

When you start WSL, that is a login shell, but when you run `exec bash` or `exec $SHELL`, that's a non-login interactive shell.  I suspect you'll see the same problem if you run `exec $SHELL -l` immediately after starting WSL, which starts a login shell instead of a non-login interactive shell.

With bash, `~/.bashrc` is not read for login shells that don't come from SSH; `~/.bash_profile` is read instead.  Since you don't want to repeat your configuration, it's customary to have `~/.bash_profile` read `~/.bashrc` by adding something like so into it:

```
# include .bashrc if it exists
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

This will make your `~/.bashrc` be read when you first start WSL, and your virtualenv code should work as normal.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this doesn't seem to solve the problem. As far as I can tell, ```~/.bashrc``` is running when I start WSL. The edits I made show up even without running ```exec $SHELL``` first. Trying to add ```~/.bash_profile``` seems to prevent ```~/.bashrc``` from running. And I also get the error ```syntax error: unexpected end of file```

Answer (score 0):

I had a differ problem that also required restart WSL2 to get everything working.

The solution was to disable **Windows Fast Startup.**

Apparently, sometimes during Fast Startup, `WSL (default)` was initialized instead of `WSL2`

You can disable it under *"Power Options"* > *"Choose what the power buttons do"* > *"Shutdown settings"* > *"Turn on fast startup"*